# How to decrypt post request message in message handler so the API controller will get JSON sobject

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to secure data that a desktop app need to get\send (by HTTP request messages)
from\to Web API. I'm doing it with EllipticCurveDiffieHellman encryption (public private key).
So if I need to send a user JSON object Ill encrypt it and then send it.
The final project will allow the user to transfer data for both sides:

PC < – > Web API < – > mobile phone app.

My question\problem is: at this moment I have a Message Handler that do the dialogue with the client side, but when all the required data checked the request need to continue to the API controller but it still encrypted. So I need to know how can I decrypt the request body message so for ex the func Post (User i_User) will get the User JSON object as it should?

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        {
            //scenarios that I check and response
        }
        //if any of the scenarios didnt match, I do the process below

        EllipticCurveDiffieHellman.Security.ClientIV = m_SecondPart.First();
         
        string encryptedMessage = string.Empty;
        string jsonDecryptedMessage = string.Empty;          
        m_OriginalContentHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        byte[] jsonBytes;       

        foreach (var header in request.Content.Headers)
        {
            if (!header.Key.Equals("Content-Length"))
            {
                m_OriginalContentHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value.First());
            }
        } 

        Stream newStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);               
        encryptedMessage = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        jsonDecryptedMessage = EllipticCurveDiffieHellman.Security.Decryption(encryptedMessage);
        jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonDecryptedMessage);
                    
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(newStream);
        streamWriter.Write(jsonDecryptedMessage);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        newStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        request.Content = new StreamContent(newStream);
                   
        foreach (var header in m_OriginalContentHeaders)
        {
            request.Content.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", string.Format("{0}", jsonBytes.Length));

        //for Testing
        StreamReader streamReaderTest = new StreamReader(newStream);
        newStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        encryptedMessage = streamReaderTest.ReadToEnd();           
        
        streamReaderTest.Close();
        streamWriter.Close();                  

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

the StreamReaderTest try to read the string I wrote to newStream and it works and I can see the headers too, but the problem is that the Post func in the API get null as a parameter.

Comment: You can get hold of the request's stream by doing `request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` and then after decryption, you can replace the request's Content with a new content like `StreamContent` having this decrypted stream...make sure to copy the original request content's headers to the new content which you are using to replace...

Comment: First 10x for your reply. I think I understood what you were saying but I cant change the stream of the request message. It says the stream is not writable.

Comment: Probably I was not clear...you cannot write to the original stream as its read-only. I was imagining like this: while decrypting the original request stream, you write out to a new memory stream and then replace the request's content with a new StreamContent having this memory stream.

Comment: Hey again, the decryption works perfect now, but still the post func in the api controller get null so I guess the problem now is with the headers. So my last question (I hope) is which headers do I need and can to copy from the original request message? I tried to copy the Content's headers but it didnt work. 10x

Comment: Excluding the `Content-Length` header, I think rest of the Content headers should be copied...Content-length should be excluded because the original request's length (based on the encrypted data) would be different than the one after decryption...if this doesn't work, could you share your code which you are using to copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //sometesting for clear process

        IDictionary<string, string> m_OriginalHeaders;
        IDictionary<string, string> m_OriginalContentHeaders;

         //sometesting for clear process
         // and if none of them response...

        EllipticCurveDiffieHellman.Security.ClientIV = m_SecondPart.First();


        string encryptedMessage = string.Empty;
        string jsonDecryptedMessage = string.Empty;
        m_OriginalContentHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        byte[] jsonBytes;

        foreach (var header in request.Content.Headers)
        {
            if (!header.Key.Equals("Content-Length"))
            {
                m_OriginalContentHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value.First());
            }
        } 

        Stream newStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);               
        encryptedMessage = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        jsonDecryptedMessage = EllipticCurveDiffieHellman.Security.Decryption(encryptedMessage);
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(newStream);
            streamWriter.Write(jsonDecryptedMessage);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            newStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            request.Content = new StreamContent(newStream);

            foreach (var header in m_OriginalContentHeaders)
            {
                request.Content.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }

            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

The problem was just one line that was unnecessary.
This works 4 me. 
And thanks to Kiran Challa for directing me to the solution.